# CodeIgniter 4 - Controller not Found

Tags: codeigniter-4

this is the first time I use Codeigniter 4

I'm already installed codeigniter 4 with composer or manual

already copy index.php and .htaccess to root when manual install and run

already run with php start spark serve too

already set baseurl

welcome_message is success run when I Write in URL `localhost:8080` or `localhost/ci4`

but when I write in URL`localhost:8080/home/index` with spark serve, show 404 - File Not Found

and when I write in URL `localhost/ci4/home/index` still show 404 - File Not Found

anyone please help me....

Comment: Share your `app/Config/Routes.php` file configurations.

Comment: I'm already have solution, I set autoroutes = true. but i saw in reference no one use this trick and they can call the controller

Answer (score 0):

- Go into Your_Project_Folder > index.php
- Change, **FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php'** to **FCPATH .'app/Config/Paths.php'**

Comment: i'm already set FCPATH, but controller still not found, I'm already have solution, I set autoroutes = true. but i saw in reference no one use this trick and they can call the controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm already have solution, in file Routes.php I set `$routes->setAutoRoute(true);`
but i saw in reference no one use this trick and they can call the controller